# Is there a way to replicate the 'Wrench' menu in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm pretty new to writing Chrome extensions. I've noticed that all of the extensions I've seen (both sample and useful) do not use the standard OS drop down menu when you click on them. Their popups tend to be pretty different and use stylesheets. Is there any way to have the extension popup be an actual OS menu (in the vein of the context menu API)?

If not, is there any place that has a stylesheet + javascript that replicates the look of a normal menu (I'm using OS X)? I know that the 'Wrench' menu that you use for changing settings has a normal looking menu. I tried looking through the source of Chromium to see whether it was implemented the same way as an extension and if it had  such a stylesheet but I could not find anything.

Comment: Using HTML/CSS is not going to give an exact look and feel of native menus, but you could make screenshots on different OSes and show a mouseover image when a menu item is hovered etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really gotten the answer I wanted for this question so I tried to hack something together myself. The following stylesheet reasonably approximates the OS X menu. The only issues are that the font is a little too short when compared to the actual menu and the gradient is a little bit off (the OS X menu is not smooth and I don't know how to do that in CSS).

You can find my attempt [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abhayb/r3rrw/)

Comment: That is awesome, I didn't notice any difference between it and any normal menu. But just a thought, a theme will change the menu colours, so your menu won't always match.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome wrench menu isn't rendered using javascript and css, it is a native GUI element of your OS, so you won't be able to find any css styles in sources.

If you want to replicate the menu look you can search for some javascript library that does that ([like this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/contextMenu/demo/)), but I've never seen something that replicates GUI menu exactly even for one OS.